# How to get a collection of strings of what Groups a user belongs to?

Tags: c#, active-directory, directoryservices

```
if (DomainHelpers.DomainExists(ConnectionString))
{
    using(var baseDirectory = new DirectoryEntry(ConnectionString))
    {
        baseDirectory.Username = Username;
        baseDirectory.Password = Password;

        using (DirectorySearcher searcher = new DirectorySearcher())
        {
            searcher.SearchRoot = baseDirectory;
            searcher.Filter = "(objectCategory=user)";
            searcher.SearchScope = SearchScope.Subtree;

            var userResults = searcher.FindAll();

            foreach (SearchResult user in userResults)
            {
                var newUser = new User();
                newUser.Name = user.Properties["name"][0].ToString();
                newUser.Path = user.Path;

                //.Groups is just a List<string>.
                newUser.Groups = user.Properties?????

                _users.Add(newUser);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

How do I retrieve a collection of groups the user belongs to?

Thank you! :)

Answer (score 1):

```
user.Properties["memberOf"]
```

don't forget to add `searcher.PropertiesToLoad.Add("memberOf");` before `...searcher.FindAll()`

To populate your property:

```
//.Groups is just a List<string>.
foreach(object group in user.Properties["memberOf"])
    newUser.Groups.Add((string)group);
```

Comment: But how would I iterate through each of the properties?

Answer (score 0):

You should use [System.DirectoryServices.AccountManagement](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.directoryservices.accountmanagement.aspx?PHPSESSID=ev0v34i8u80gkmn37sd8r65363).  It's much easier.  Here is a nice code project [article](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/system/usingAccountManagement.aspx) giving you an overview on all the classes in this DLL.

It's really hard to get it right using `DirectoryEntry`.  First of all, getting `memberOf` attribute doesn't give you primary group.  Also, if the user has a domain local group from another domain, it won't show up in `memberOf` attribute.  You can check [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms677943%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) for details.  Here is how the code looks like if you switch to use System.DirectoryServices.AccountManagement.  The following code can find the immediate groups this user assigned to, which includes the primary group.

```
UserPrincipal user = UserPrincipal.FindByIdentity(new PrincipalContext (ContextType.Domain, "mydomain.com"), IdentityType.SamAccountName, "username");
foreach (GroupPrincipal group in user.GetGroups())
{
    Console.Out.WriteLine(group);
}
```